# Only regular wrench key for wheel mount like this?

Tags: axle

With the wheel mounting system like on the photos (sorry for poor quality - this is the best my phone can do) - is my only option to dismount a wheel is to use a wrench? Wheels: CUBE RA 0.8 CX. On the left side it seems that there's a visible thread but I'm not sure what is it for. The ride side shows the end of the axle so I guess nothing to do there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the axle you have is the right one for the frame and too short - there is a lot of thread exposed in the right side. Worth a read - https://wheelbuilder.com/blog/thru-axles-demystified-/ - the correct axle needs to be the right length, have the right amount of thread of the right pitch, and have the right seat.

Comment: Wow, that's actually a very useful note @mattnz. The reason I started to look at the the wheel now is that I found out that the casette is a bit loose. I'll see if I can get LBS to install a proper axle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a thru-axle that has lost its handle. You can see the threaded bit in the first photo where a handle should have been bolted in. This can happen if the retaining bolt vibrates loose during a ride.

[image]

Luckily the axle has flats so can be removed with a wrench but you’ll want to track down a new axle for when you need to remove the wheel by hand when out on the road/trail.

It’s probably a 12mm x 142mm rear thru-axle but length will need measuring against the current part along with the seat type (square or conical) , thread pitch and thread length. The frame manufacturer (Cube) might provide you with an exact specification.

[This blog](https://wheelbuilder.com/blog/thru-axles-demystified-/) discusses the technical differences in depth very well.

**EDIT** Changed last paragraph because thru-axles are not standardised.

Comment: No all thru-axles have handles, I know mine has none, it needs a allen-key 5 to remove.

Comment: @pelle true, and a few have QR style cams to lock in place. Any replacement just needs to fit to length.

Comment: Not just length, thread pitch and seat can also vary. Bicycle component standards are now a dogs breakfast straight out of  XKCD https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @mattnz yeah , I noticed that blog too and edited the post. It’s like everyone wants their own proprietary version and good luck finding a replacement 5 years down the track.